# How to open the next message in the currently selected mailbox in mail.app

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

When viewing a message in a separate window in Apple Mail (Mountain Lion), how can I open the next message in the list with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: is it from same conversation ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 no, I don't like the conversation metaphor in email either so switch those features off wherever I can.

Comment: just asking :) how about open new viewer window option-cmd-n

Answer (score 7):

I found navigating email in a thread incredibly frustrating especially for long email that have hundreds of lines of quoted text, and was trying to find the answer to this.

So here goes:

- first highlight an email in a thread: click next to the title, the email borders should be highlighted
- use the right/left arrow buttons to go to the next/previous email in this thread

Comment: Life saving tip!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do that as far I know.

While in Open message window to see next message use the <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard shortcut for opening the Next Message (as of Monterey 12.4). It is also not possible to create a shortcut using preferences, as the Mail app has no action available for this.

Not what you wanted, but you can *archive* or *move* the email you are reading, so that it gets out of the way and you will have the next email in view.

Archive this message: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>